# sqlite value wont update

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Im trying to update custommer ("cliente") information in an Sqlite database but there's just one value that wont update. When I tried to update the column 'fechaDeuda' (date of debt) it just wont do it. Weird thing is: I've coded a function to handle all updates and it works fine with all the other cases, even when being called in 'Problematic Line' (see code below) the function executes every statement of the database update and does not throw any exception but still **the value in dataBase doesnt change**.

Here's the code where I update three values on the same row:

```
try:
    table = 'clientes'
    _cliente = sqGenericSelectOne(table, None, 'id', generic.id)  # This function retrieves one row based on the arguments passed
    clienteID = _cliente[0]
    fecha = date_time.split(' - ')[0]
    sqUpdateOne(table, 'fechaDeuda', fecha, 'id', clienteID)  #### Problematic line (!!!)
    nuevoSaldo = float(_cliente[9]) - _pago
    if nuevoSaldo < 0:
        nuevoSaldo = 0
    sqUpdateOne(table, 'saldo', nuevoSaldo, 'id', clienteID)  # This line works fine
    nuevoTotalPagado = float(_cliente[11]) + _pago
    sqUpdateOne(table, 'totalPagado', nuevoTotalPagado, 'id', clienteID)  # This one works fine too
except Exception as e:
    error(0, e)
```

**Edit (for some reason this got erased when I posted)**Heres the 'sqUpdateOne' code:

```
# Sqlite database value updater
def sqUpdateOne(table, column, newValue, refColumn, refValue):
    try:
        with conn:
            c.execute(f'''UPDATE {table} SET {column} = {newValue} WHERE {refColumn} = {refValue}''')
            print()
            return
    except Exception as e:
        error(3, e, table)
        return
```

And here's how the dataBase table 'clientes' is created in case it's necessary. The table works fine for everything else. I keep track of it using https://sqliteonline.com/

```
 table = 'clientes'
        try:
            c.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE {table} (
            id integer,
            nombre text,
            apellido text,
            valoracion real,
            direccion text,
            tel_1 text,
            tel_2 text,
            correo text,
            cantServicios integer,
            saldo real,
            fechaDeuda text,
            totalPagado real,
            descripcion text)''')
            state(2)
        except Exception as e:
            error(2, e, table)
```

**Edit:** I add here screenshot of `sqUpdateOne` when called to update 'fecha' so you guys can see the values it gets (again, it works perfectly fine in all other cases):
[image]

And heres a screenshot of the dataBase's content before *trying* to update it (it remains the same *after*)
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `fecha` is not an empty string? The problem maybe in this line: `fecha = date_time.split(' - ')[0]`

Comment: No, I checked several times and `sqUpdateOne` recieves the correct string. I'll edit the post and upload a screenshot of the debugger in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting an exception when you execute the `sqUpdateOne()` for the column `fechaDeuda` because the query string is not quite correct. As it's a text column you need to enclose the value in quotes.

So change how you are setting the variable `fecha` to wrap it in quotes:

```
fecha = f'"{date_time.split(' - ')[0]}"'
```

A sidenote: you could also remove the explicit `return` statements in `sqUpdateOne()` as you return from the function any way after these lines.

Comment: I've learnt from [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd-0G0MigUA&t=1598s) (24:55 time mark) that I dont need to commit the changes if my `execute` statement is inside a `with` statement (wich makes the conection, commits  and closes the conection by itself). But im gonna try that anyway. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh and thanks for the advice about the return statements